# How to give empty space between rows of listview?

Tags: android

In my application I have a requirement of listview with empty spaces between rows of list.So that I can give background to each row and it will look something like blocks of rows.

I tried my best but didnt find any solution.

Comment: can you give demo image that shows what actually you want ??..please attach some demo/example image to show what you really want...

Comment: you can set padding (part of view) and margin (not part of view so will get ListView background) for every view in the ListView

Comment: I am using pulltorefresh listview api to get the functionality of facebook apps in android.I am developing app which has functionality same as facebook app.please help me to get that issue solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:divider` and `android:dividerHeight` to customize the spacing between rows.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#FF0000"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am developing app which has a functionality of facebook. In one of my screen I need to display newsfeed of user.

Comment: I am developing app which has a functionality of facebook. In one of my screen I need to display newsfeed of user.In the facebook app as we find the list looks like blocks of rows.I just want to give that functinality to my screen.I am using pulltorefresh listview concept.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except I needed to set the divider programatically because the view was dynamically generated. I'm posting this answer because it was my first google hit for future reference.
You need a custom `Drawable`.
Create a new file with the following code:
`drawable/list_divider.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size
        android:height="16dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Inside your java code you need to get a reference to your `ListView` and set the divider like this:

```
listView.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_divider));
```

The result is exactly the same.