# listview rows customization

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to give empty space between rows of listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099714/how-to-give-empty-space-between-rows-of-listview)
>   [How to give empty space between pulltorefresh -listview items or rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099832/how-to-give-empty-space-between-pulltorefresh-listview-items-or-rows)

In my app I have a requirement of having a custom listView.  I want to have empty gap between the rows, so that it looks like some blocks of rows.

I tried by keeping padding in my row XML, but didn't find solution.

I am using `pullToRefresh` ListView api to refresh the list.

Answer (score 1):

ListView calculates the ListView row on the fly so setting things like margins on the ListItem  root layout doesn't always work.

Simpler solution:

create a custom drawable (res/drawable/listview_spacer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- #00000000 is transparent -->
     <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

Then set the ListView with the following attributes:

```
<ListView 
  ...
  android:divider="@drawable/listview_spacer"
  android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
```

And that will create a transparent space of 10dp between your list items.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You may write your own adapter for ListView.
Look this tutorials [custom ListView 1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429), [custom ListView 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
Then you'll be able to create a layout file for a ListView row and customize its appearance